# Strings being cut off when running numpy.insert()

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm getting an issue where if I have a numpy array with strings already inside it, every time I use `insert` to add strings, their length seems to be limited by the longest string already inside the array.

Here's a simple demonstration of my issue:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array(["xxxxx", "yyyyy", "zzzzz"])

# insert at index 1
arr1 = np.insert(arr1, obj=1, values=["1234567890", "longer string"], axis=0)

print(arr1)
```

When I run this code, the following is printed:

`['xxxxx' '12345' 'longe' 'yyyyy' 'zzzzz']`

Is there a workaround (or something I'm missing) to this?

Comment: `numpy` normally stores strings with a fixed `Un` dtype..  Adding or saving a longer string does not change that.  Using `object` dtype stores pointers to python strings, same as in a python list.  numpy does not offer much of a benefit over lists when handling strings.

Comment: Using `insert` many times is inefficient.  Like `concatenate` it makes a whole array each time.  Often list of strings are better.

Comment: Specify a longer string dttype when creating the array: `arr1 = np.array(["xxxxx", "yyyyy", "zzzzz"], dtype='U20')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print `arr1.dtype` before insert, you would see `dtype('<U5')`, which means the string elements are capped at `5` characters. You would need to convert `arr1` to a usual list or object type:

```
arr1 = arr1.astype('object')
```

so you can insert strings with any length.

Comment: `pandas` uses the `object` dtype for strings, instead of wrestling with the 'Un' dtype. For many strings about the same size, the 'Un' style potentially saves memory.